# Paste a formula into a range of cells using macros

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to paste a formula into a range of cells (I only want it to paste until the last used row of column K), but I keep getting a syntax error

```
With ThisWorkbook
With .Sheets("Ex")
    lRow4 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng4 = .Range("J6:J" & lRow4)
    rng4. FormulaR1C1."=IF(RC[1]='Lease & RPM Charges'!R[-4]C[-6],UPPER(TEXT(REPLACE(REPLACE('Lease & RPM Charges'!R[-4]C[-7],5,0,""-""),8,0,""-""),""DD-mmm-YY"")))"
End With

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

```
.Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

gives you the last used row of column 1 which is column A.
You can use …

```
.Cells(.Rows.count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
```

instead, to get the last used row in column K.

---

Also `rng4. FormulaR1C1.` should be `rng4.FormulaR1C1 =`

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ex")
    lRow4 = .Cells(.Rows.count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng4 = .Range("J6:J" & lRow4)
    rng4.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]='Lease & RPM Charges'!R[-4]C[-6],UPPER(TEXT(REPLACE(REPLACE('Lease & RPM Charges'!R[-4]C[-7],5,0,""-""),8,0,""-""),""DD-mmm-YY"")))"
End With
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but I still have syntax errors

Comment: @Leena If you don't tell which error and in which line we cannot help.

Comment: @Leena I did this code in my workbook and works fine until the last line of code because my excel isn't english so it wouldn't work. I believe u have the formula wrong, missing something that would give you an error if you try to do it manually.

Comment: @Damian this works on any localization because `FormulaR1C1` takes the english formula. `FormulaR1C1Local` is for for a localized formula (non english formula). So the code above will work on any language version. Still the formula might be wrong, so leena should check the formula.

Comment: All it says is 'Compile Error: Syntax Error', and its in the same formula line

Comment: The formula work when I copy it into the cell manually, but it doesn't work in the macro

Comment: If you get a *compile error* you didn't do exactly what I said. Copy the last code of my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed out one of the " 's